# How to Import multiple excel tables to database using jfilechooser?

Tags: java, excel

Here is sample of code, which I use for input Excel file in MySQL database.

Now, this is working with single excel table (file), but how can i import multiple files, is that even possible?

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File ("c:\\"));
fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
fc.setDialogTitle("Učitaj fajl");
fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel file","xls","xlsx"));
fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

File fi = fc.getSelectedFile();

FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fi);
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

JFileChooser has a method getSelectedFiles() that returns an array of selected files. You can iterate over that. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFiles--